# Reducing transaction timeout in JTA with Atomikos

Tags: java, transactions, timeout, jta, atomikos

I'm trying to reduce the default timeout of 300 seconds with JTA + Atomikos. However, it's not working as it keeps taking 300 seconds to time out.

What I want to do is:

- `UserTransaction`: Set the timeout to 10 seconds.
- `UserTransactionManager`: Set timeout to 10 seconds.

```java
UserTransactionImp userTransaction = new UserTransactionImp();

userTransaction.setTransactionTimeout(10);

// ...

UserTransactionManager transactionManager= new UserTransactionManager();
transactionManager.setTransactionTimeout(10); // may not be necessary as I do set this on the transaction

// ...

JtaTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager = new JtaTransactionManager(userTransaction,transactionManager);

// ...

TransactionTemplate templ = new TransactionTemplate(jtaTransactionManager, new DefaultTransaction());

templ.execute(callback -> {
  // code to update the DB
})
```

How I am testing this:

1. Locking a row via SQLDeveloper,
2. Try to update the same row via the app,
3. Keeps waiting for the lock,
4. Times out eventually.

I expected this to time out after 10 seconds based on the setting I have done above. However, it keeps on waiting for 300 seconds before it times out.

Not sure where else I need to configure this.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the TransactionsEssentials JTA settings can be tweaked using the `jta.properties` file (placed at the root of your classpath) or `transactions.properties` (also can be placed in your main resources folder)

The configurations of interest are:

| Property name | Description | Since |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout` | Specifies the maximum timeout (in milliseconds) that can be allowed for transactions. Defaults to 300000. This means that calls to UserTransaction.setTransactionTimeout() with a value higher than configured here will be max'ed to this value. For 4.x or higher, a value of 0 means no maximum (i.e., unlimited timeouts are allowed). NOTE: as of 5.0, using 0 interferes with recovery. Instead, use Long.MAX_VALUE to specify unlimited. | 3.x, 4.x |
| `com.atomikos.icatch.default_jta_timeout` | The default timeout for JTA transactions (optional, defaults to 10000 ms) | 3.4, 4.x |

So if you configured your `transactions.properties` file with:

```yaml
# transactions.properties
# .../src/main/resources/transactions.properties
# Max timeout for any JTA transactions. (10 seconds)
com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout=10000
# Default timeout for any JTA transactions. (5 seconds)
com.atomikos.icatch.default_jta_timeout=5000
```

It should do the trick to allow for a maximum of 10 seconds.

See: [Atomikos - JtaProperties - Transaction manager](https://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/JtaProperties?sortcol=0;table=5;up=0#JVM_40System_41_Properties)